# Does node-cron run tasks in parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-cron

I have some scheduled tasks in my node app. These are scheduled using [node-cron](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron). I just want to confirm onething. By using node-cron, will these tasks be executed in parallel? I am aware that node.js is single threaded. By using node-cron, will I be able to run sub tasks in parallel?

If node-cron does not spawn child processeses for scheduled jobs, is there any library that would help me to achieve this?

I have tried this code. Once the scheduled task is executed, the other scheduler is never get executed. So apparantly node-cron does not spawn child processes.

```
let cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', ()=>
{
    console.log("Every minute", new Date());
});
cron.schedule('*/2 * * * * *', ()=>
{
    while (true) {
        console.log("Hello..... from scheduler");
    }
});
```

Comment: Searching for "node-cron" found [their GitHub page](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) where it notes, in the README, "We also allow you to execute a job external to the javascript process using `child_process`"

Comment: I am referring to https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron

Comment: Well, now you know of a library that does spawn child processes... :)